# Recursive function persist results in js

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have following code to get all the names of the items in order such that name1, name2, name3, name31, name32 ... and so on, also setting some selected to true or false based on some condition. I am trying to solve it using recursive function. But I don't know how to persist the results and return them at the end.

```
arr = [
    {
      name: 'name1',
      selected: true,
      children: [
        { name: 'name2', selected: false, children: [] },
        {
          name: 'name3',
          selected: false,
          children: [
            { name: 'name31', selected: false, children: [] },
            {
              name: 'name32',
              selected: false,
              children: [
                { name: 'name321', selected: false, children: [] },
                { name: 'name322', selected: false, children: [] },
                { name: 'name323', selected: false, children: [] },
              ],
            },
            { name: 'name33', selected: false, children: [] },
          ],
        },
        { name: 'name4', selected: false, children: [] },
      ],
    },
  ];

  myfunc(items) {
    const result = [];
    for (const item of items) {
      item.selected = false;
      myfunc(item.children);
      result.push(item.name);
    }
    return result;
  }

 const result = myfunc(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `names` using `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```js
const names = t =>
  t.flatMap(v => [ v.name, ...names(v.children) ])

names(arr)
// ...
```

```
["name1", "name2", "name3", "name31", "name32", "name321", "name322", "name323", "name33", "name4"]
```

Comment: Yes, although note that this is only half the question.  See mine for an approach to the other half.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that for the two things you're trying to do, finding a list of names and changing some of the `select` values, you do them in two separate functions.

You can always write a wrapper function that does both, but there are unrelated requirements for the two; combining them adds unnecessary complexity.

There is already a good solution here for the names.  See the answer from Thankyou.

For the other requirement, I would suggest that you separate into three distinct pieces.  "Setting some selected to true or false based on some condition," is two pieces: one for testing your condition, the other is for making the change.  The third part would be the code to do the actual traversal of your data.  (Also, there might be a fourth; my example below assumes that you do something to the data only if the condition is true, but you could have two different actions to run: one if it's true, another if it's false.)

You don't actually describe your condition, so I'll make one up.  I'm going to say that the condition is true if the digits at the end of the `name` make an odd number.  And we need a function to return a version of the object with `selected` set to true.  Here are two simple helper functions for those:

```js
const nameIsOdd = ({name}) =>
  Number (name .replace (/\D/g, '')) % 2 === 1

const selectedTrue = ({select, ...rest}) =>
  ({...rest, selected: true})
```

(Note that I say we return an object with the updated property.  I prefer to work with data as immutable, and return an altered version of my structure rather than make changes to one.)

Now we can write a function to recursively traverse an array of objects that have `children` properties, accepting a predicate function and one to create the updated node.  It's actually fairly simple:

```js
const alterNodes = (pred, change) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({children = [], ...rest}) => ({
    ... (pred (rest) ? change (rest) : rest),
    children: alterNodes (pred, change) (children)
  }))
```

Using that, we now write our main function very simply:

```
const fixSelected = alterNodes (nameIsOdd, selectedTrue)
```

You can see this in action in the following snippet:

```js
const alterNodes = (pred, change) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({children = [], ...rest}) => ({
    ... (pred (rest) ? change (rest) : rest),
    children: alterNodes (pred, change) (children)
  }))

const nameIsOdd = ({name}) =>
  Number (name .replace (/\D/g, '')) % 2 === 1

const selectedTrue = ({select, ...rest}) =>
  ({...rest, selected: true})

const fixSelected = alterNodes (nameIsOdd, selectedTrue)

const arr = [{name: 'name1', selected: true, children: [{name: 'name2', selected: false, children: []}, {name: 'name3', selected: false, children: [{name: 'name31', selected: false, children: []}, {name: 'name32', selected: false, children: [{name: 'name321', selected: false, children: []}, {name: 'name322', selected: false, children: []}, {name: 'name323', selected: false, children: []}]}, {name: 'name33', selected: false, children: []}]}, {name: 'name4', selected: false, children: []}]}];

console .log (fixSelected (arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = [];
function myfunc(items) {
    items.forEach((item)=>{
        item.selected = false;
        result.push(item.name);
        myfunc(item.children)
    })
    return result;
 }
```

Move the result outside of function, otherwise it would be declared with each call and it's value will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized result variable inside recursive call which will return initial value only, all iterated values will be omitted.

This will work,

```
temp = [];
function myfunc(items) {
    for (item of items) {
        temp.push(item.name);
        if (typeof item.children !== 'undefined') {
            myfunc(item.children);
        }
    }
    return temp; //this is optional, use temp directly
}
const result = myfunc(arr);
```